# VS2005 debugger disassembly window

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005, platform-builder

I use PB 6.0 to debug my Windows-CE image. Whenever I run in this mode VS2005 opens the disassembly window each time it hits a debug break in a file that it does not have its source (pdb file for the module). This is really annoying as I would like to stick to the output view. I could find a setting to disable this disassembly window automatic opening. Tools->options->debugging->general-> deselecting "show disassembly if source is not available" did not help.

My question:

Does anyone know how to disable this disassembly window automatic activation?

Thanks,
Shai

Answer (score 2):

goto Visual Studio Menu in that Select Tools => Option => Debugging => General

and uncheck the Show Disassembly if source is not available

it will disable DisAssemble at bebug time

i
think it will work fine

Ajay Patel

Comment: Unfortunately, the Show Disassembly option is not checked and it still happens.